# Rearrange order of child components

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm writing a slider style navigation in React Native, where you slide away the topmost item in a pile of cards and it (should) move to the bottom of the pile.

However, since there is no zIndex in React Native, only the order of elements, I'm having a hard time actually moving it to the back.

Given a collection of elements in `{this.props.children}`, how can I take the topmost element, move it to the back and re-render the component with the new order?

I have tried moving the children to the state and doing things like this:

```
this.setState({
    children: this.state.children.push(this.state.children.shift())
})
```

But I've had no success. `state.children` is set to undefined in this case.

Is there a *right* way to rearrange elements since there is no zIndex?

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push()` is an in-place method, which updates the array and does not return anything.

You can just call `push()` and `this.setState({ children: this.state.children })`. Instead of setState, you can also use `this.forceUpdate()` since the reference in the state doesn't really change.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed there was som issues with the push/shift and why it returned `undefined`. Something is in fact changing since I'm moving an element from the start of the array to the end. It's fixed now and works, but it still feels like a really bad way of rearranging components to achieve zIndex in React.

Comment: The array is changing, but this.state.children still points to the same Array. That means the `state` doesn't change when only looking at the first level of references. I agree that this might not be the best way to achieve what you want though.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Solved it with `.splice(0)` to clone the array and replace the old one. Really ugly, but works until I find a better solution to rearranging the child components.